# Exception when event handler plugin is invoked

Tags: event-handling, identity, identity-management, oim, identitymanager

I have created the OIM Event Handler and imported metadata too. I can see the metadata file is imported successfully and can be seen when metadata is exported.

I have created the folder structure for plugin and copied the folder structure as is to the plugins directory as I am working on dev.
This event handler gets trigger when we create User
But when I am invoking create User I am getting following exception on UI.

```
null 

Error 
oracle.iam.platform.pluginframework.PluginException: Failed to load plugin <fullyqualifiedclasssname of EventHandler> for plugin point Id oracle.iam.platform.kernel.spi.EventHandler 

Error 
Failed to load plugin <fullyqualifiedclasssname of EventHandler> for plugin point Id oracle.iam.platform.kernel.spi.EventHandler
```

I also tried registering the plugin, but it NEVER gives response as plugin registered successfully with version.

Comment: Can you share the plugin and metadata xml files, it will be easy to dbug then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening due to bin folder is getting included while creating jar. I checked the jar and I found this issue. This is resolved now!